# Column that counts number of time an element appears and average in r

Tags: r, formatting, format

An example of the data set I have is given below.

```
Month_Ori_Dest   Cat    Num  
1-LA/LON          A      2
1-LA/LON          A      3
2-LON/LA          B      2
3-LON/LA          A      5
3-LON/LA          B      2
```

1) Firstly I want to group by Month_Ori_Dest and Cat and insert a column that calculates the number of times that combination appears. E.g.

```
Month_Ori_Dest   Cat    Num  Count
1-LA/LON          A      2     2
1-LA/LON          A      3     2
2-LON/LA          B      2     1
3-LON/LA          A      5     1
3-LON/LA          B      2     1
```

2) I then want to insert a column based on the same groupings (Month_Ori_Dest and Cat) to calculate the average Num for each group. E.G.

```
Month_Ori_Dest   Cat    Num  Count  AverageNum
1-LA/LON          A      2     2        2.5
1-LA/LON          A      3     2        2.5
2-LON/LA          B      2     1         2
3-LON/LA          A      5     1         5
3-LON/LA          B      2     1         2
```

Any help would be great.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% group_by(Month_Ori_Dest,Cat) %>% 
        mutate(Count=n(), AverageNum=mean(Num, na.rm=TRUE))

 # A tibble: 5 x 5
 # Groups:   Month_Ori_Dest, Cat [4]
  Month_Ori_Dest Cat     Num    Count    AverageNum
  <chr>          <chr> <int> <int> <dbl>
1 1-LA/LON       A         2     2   2.5
2 1-LA/LON       A         3     2   2.5
3 2-LON/LA       B         2     1   2  
4 3-LON/LA       A         5     1   5  
5 3-LON/LA       B         2     1   2
```

## Data

```
df1 <- read.table(text="
                    Month_Ori_Dest   Cat    Num  
  1-LA/LON          A      2
  1-LA/LON          A      3
  2-LON/LA          B      2
  3-LON/LA          A      5
  3-LON/LA          B      2
                     ",header=T, stringsAsFactors = F)
```

Comment: That's perfect and very simple. Thank you :)